# Animation of a torus using exterior/interior radius

Tags: animation, transforms

I want to animate a torus with a fixed exterior radius and moving interior radius.

**I've already  tried** : to modelize using major/minor radius with bezier curves but it doesn't help me to solve the problem.

I've also tried to seek informations about using bezier to make a controlled torus with exterior/ interior circle parameters

[image: Initial form]

[image: Final form]

I want to make continuous transformation from the first to the last have you an idea of how I could do this,

Thank you very much !

Comment: with shapekeys and you scale it a bit so that the outer radius stays the same?

Comment: Could you please develop my friend ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use *Shape Keys*: Create a torus, create 2 shape keys, select the second one, in *Edit* mode fatten it (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>), and scale down the whole torus until the outer radius matches its previous length, use the 3D cursor as a reference:

[image]

Another idea, inspired by Lemon: Create a circle, make it rotate around with a *Screw* modifier in order to create a torus, create 2 shape keys, select the second, scale up to thickens the torus (use the 3D cursor as *Pivot Point*):

[image]

[image]

Also you can do it with a curve's bevel object (*Properties panel > Object Data > Geometry > Bevel*), just put the bevel object's origin on one of its vertices, and scale:

[image]

Comment: Thank you but i don't know how to make appears the Shape Keys

Comment: waht do you mean by "maje appers"?

Comment: I mistape modified make appears

Comment: go in the Properties panel > Object Data > Shape Keys, create 2 shape keys with the "+" button, select the second shape key, go in Edit mode, scale, switch back to Object mode, play with the Value

Comment: Thanks how do you do to change only interior radius in edit mode ?

Comment: you must first fatten (Alt S), it will change the outer radius, then scale down the whole torus until it goes back to the good outer radius, use the 3D cursor as a reference

Comment: I would go with the Curves, that way you can keep it all procedural.. at least that's how I would have done it. And just by moving the origin of the Bevel object you can switch between keeping outer diameter, keeping inner diameter, growing upwards, growing downwards....

Answer (score 2):

Just a slight variation on @moonboots' "A" answer..

- Create 2 Tori, using the 'Exterior / Interior' creation settiings, varying the 'Interior' radius.
- Decide one of them is your master torus, select both, with the master active.

[image]

- In the master's *Data* tab, *Shape Keys* panel, using the dropdown menu from the down-chevron on the right of the panel, hit 'Join as Shapes'

Now, with the shape-key selected in the panel,  by sliding the newly created 'Value' field below the panel, you can animate between the inner radii.